# combining purrr and cowplot to make a plot grid

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, cowplot

I have created a list column of `ggplot2` figures using `purrr` and now I would like to use `cowplot::plot_grid()` to combine them into a single plot. How can I do this? There is a brute force way to do this, but that may not work when I don't *a priori* know how many elements are going to be in the list column.

```r
### libraries needed
library(tidyverse)
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot")

### creating list column with plots
plots <- datasets::mtcars %>%
  dplyr::mutate(.data = ., cyl2 = cyl) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(.data = ., cyl) %>%
  tidyr::nest(data = .) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    .data = .,
    plot = data %>%
      purrr::map(
        .x = .,
        .f = ~ ggstatsplot::ggbetweenstats(
          data = .,
          x = am,
          y = mpg,
          title = as.character(.$cyl2)
        )
      )
  )
#> Warning:  aesthetic `x` was not a factor; converting it to factorReference:  Welch's t-test is used as a default. (Delacre, Lakens, & Leys, International Review of Social Psychology, 2017).Note:  Bartlett's test for homogeneity of variances: p-value =  0.317Warning:  aesthetic `x` was not a factor; converting it to factorReference:  Welch's t-test is used as a default. (Delacre, Lakens, & Leys, International Review of Social Psychology, 2017).Note:  Bartlett's test for homogeneity of variances: p-value =  0.144Warning:  aesthetic `x` was not a factor; converting it to factorReference:  Welch's t-test is used as a default. (Delacre, Lakens, & Leys, International Review of Social Psychology, 2017).Note:  Bartlett's test for homogeneity of variances: p-value =  0.201

### creating a grid with cowplot

# brute force way to do this would be
# this works fine with 3 plots, but I might have way more plots than that
cowplot::plot_grid(plots$plot[[1]],
                   plots$plot[[2]],
                   plots$plot[[3]],
                   nrow = 3,
                   ncol = 1, 
                   labels = c("(a)","(b)","(c)"))
```

[image]

```r
# searching for a more tidy and elegant way to do this
# my attempted code
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = list(plots$plot),
                     nrow = 3,
                     ncol = 1, 
                     labels = c("(a)","(b)","(c)"))
#> Error in plot_to_gtable(x): Argument needs to be of class "ggplot", "gtable", "grob", "recordedplot", or a function that plots to an R graphicsdevice when called, but is a list
```

Created on 2018-03-12 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`plots$plot` is already a list of plots, so all you need to do is call

```
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = plots$plot)
```